# Sorround a #text node with a SPAN node

Tags: html, dom

I have an html page with some text entered by user. The user can put any kind of formatted text, can insert images, videos, smile, can align the text as he/she prefer etc.
In short, the document is fully created by the user through the use of an editor ([CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)).

My application must then take that html text (DOM tree) and make certain operations.

Because I need to be able to manipulate each individual node in the tree, I would associate a data attribute to all nodes, including nodes *#text*.
However, I can't bind attributes to *#text* nodes. So I thought to surround the #text nodes with a SPAN node.
So I treat SPAN nodes as #text nodes.

**The editor doesn't allow the user to create directly HTML.**

This could be problematic? Can SPAN node be child of all nodes?

For example, in these cases there aren't problems:

```
<p>Some text <b>here</b></p>

<img src=".."><a>a link here</a>

<address><span>an address</span></address><br>
```

But there may be cases in which to place a SPAN could create problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can SPAN node be child of all nodes?

No. For example, `option` elements allow text content but a `span` element would be invalid HTML.

However, theoretically, with DOM methods you can append whatever element as a child of whatever other element (except cycles). The result might be invalid HTML and be displayed unreliably, but the DOM doesn't care.

```js
var s = document.createElement('span');
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Bar'));
document.querySelector('option').appendChild(s);
document.write('Span inserted successfully');
```

```html
<select><option>Foo</option></select>
```

But if you want to associate data to nodes you can try ES6 WeakMap instead of attributes.

```
var data = new WeakMap();
data.set(textNode, whateverData);
data.get(textNode); // whateverData
```